# Having a problem loading the Android Emulator in Eclipse. All it says is ANDROID_. Any suggestions?

Tags: android, emulation

I went through the simple hello world application on the android developers forums to an absolute T. But, when I start the emulator all it comes up with is a large black screen that just says ANDROID_. The '_' is flashing. Does anyone know what may have caused this or why it is not working.

Comment: It takes a _very_ long time for the emulator to start. The good news is that once started it seldom has to be shut down (unless you want to emulate a different device). Even if your app crashes or hangs, you can just kill the process and the emulator usually remains stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can take a while to start. Remember it is emulating an ARM processor so that can take a while depending on the specs of your machine. Start it and give it 5 min. If it hasn't come up by then you may want to close and restart. While it is starting up, if you open ddms you can follow what is going on in logcat.

Good news is that if you enable snapshots, once you get it started and saved (it does this on its own). Subsequent starts should be pretty quick.

Answer (score 2):

For some reasons, the android emulator does not work properly on any of the laptop's i have. It lags even on my high end laptop with  4 gb Ram, i5 processor and 1 gig graphics processor, so i connect my phone using usb cable, enable debugging mode and run the app on the phone from eclipse. You will need a working adb connection as stated on android developer website though. It works pretty good and is way better than using an emulator. :)

Answer (score 1):

It takes about 3 mins for the emulator to load on a laptop. Wait for about 5-6 mins if not. close it.

In case when you restart still you get the same, go to AVD Manager delete the image and create a new one.

Comment: It can take a lot more than three minutes to start, depending on the system.

Comment: @Ted Yeah it takes awhile, it sucks. Just wait.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, the emulator is very, very slow to start up.  It can get wedged on startup for me, every now and again, but shutting it down and trying a second time almost always works.  And yes, you can leave it running the whole time, but note that Eclipse and/or ADB can get wedged as well.  You'll see logcat stop updating inside of Eclipse.  I can usually get it restarted by doing

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Sometimes, just doing an adb logcat on a command line will get things moving again.  Good luck.